# Alternative of GCC libstdc++ Profile Mode

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, std

I saw that the libstdc++ Profile Mode has been deprecated recently (see [GCC 7 changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html)).

I just know that the [Profile Mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/profile_mode.html) provides some useful suggestions about the usage of c++ standard library. But since it is deprecated, how to get similar suggestions instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at Callgrind and KCacheGrind as UI. A quick search presented these results:

- [How to profile C++ application with Callgrind / KCacheGrind](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2011/09/profile-c-application-with-callgrind-kcachegrind.html)
- [Callgrind: Profile a specific part of my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688185/callgrind-profile-a-specific-part-of-my-code)

Comment: General profiling is quite different. Libstdc++'s profile mode was specifically about the library, looking for instance at your pattern of insert/remove/traversal in each std::list, and suggesting to replace it with std::vector or std::deque if it would better fit that pattern.